# Good factor loadings in a one factor model, but poor loadings once model is added to full SEM (lavaan - RStudio)

Tags: r, binary-data, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

So I have been trying to reproduce a logistic SEM with a binary outcome (not relevant to this question). The sample size after removing missing values is around 820. One of my predictor latent factors called FR is as follows:

```
cfa_FR = 'FR =~ WRKHSW+WRKFRM+WRKPAY+ABSWRK'
```

**Maybe it is relevant to note that all four observed variables are binary.** When I perform cfa on this factor, I get the following output:

```
Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|) ci.lower ci.upper   Std.lv  Std.all
  Fam_Resp =~                                                                             
    WRKHSW            1.000                               1.000    1.000    3.972    0.648
    WRKFRM            1.586    0.111   14.225    0.000    1.367    1.804    6.299    0.678
    WRKPAY            1.186    0.083   14.351    0.000    1.024    1.348    4.711    0.719
    ABSWRK            1.005    0.097   10.371    0.000    0.815    1.194    3.990    0.432

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|) ci.lower ci.upper   Std.lv  Std.all
   .WRKHSW            1.696    0.203    8.369    0.000    1.299    2.093    1.696    0.277
   .WRKFRM            2.581    0.307    8.406    0.000    1.980    3.183    2.581    0.278
   .WRKPAY            2.472    0.217   11.416    0.000    2.048    2.897    2.472    0.377
   .ABSWRK            2.899    0.306    9.485    0.000    2.300    3.499    2.899    0.314
    FR                0.000                               0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|) ci.lower ci.upper   Std.lv  Std.all
   .WRKHSW           21.812    1.397   15.609    0.000   19.073   24.551   21.812    0.580
   .WRKFRM           46.620    3.213   14.508    0.000   40.322   52.919   46.620    0.540
   .WRKPAY           20.717    1.620   12.789    0.000   17.542   23.892   20.717    0.483
   .ABSWRK           69.581    3.541   19.652    0.000   62.642   76.521   69.581    0.814
    FR               15.777    1.721    9.168    0.000   12.404   19.149    1.000    1.000

R-Square:
                   Estimate
    WRKHSW            0.420
    WRKFRM            0.460
    WRKPAY            0.517
    ABSWRK            0.186
```

Fit measures are super good as well. However, once I fit this into my SEM model with other latent predictors **only (without logistic regression)**, two of the variables, ABSWRK and WRKPAY load poorly on FR:

```
Latent Variables:
                           Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  SE =~                                                       
    SE1                       1.000                               0.626    0.733
    SE2                       0.641    0.054   11.868    0.000    0.401    0.481
    SE3                       0.839    0.054   15.592    0.000    0.525    0.665
    SE4                       0.732    0.057   12.882    0.000    0.458    0.527
    SE5                       0.644    0.048   13.354    0.000    0.403    0.549
  SA =~                                                            
    SA1                       1.000                               0.555    0.500
    SA2                       1.369    0.134   10.196    0.000    0.760    0.569
    SA3                       1.465    0.135   10.850    0.000    0.813    0.672
    SA4                       0.576    0.066    8.666    0.000    0.320    0.431
  FR =~                                                      
    ABSWRK                    1.000                               0.050    0.116
    WRKFRM                    6.803    2.476    2.748    0.006    0.343    0.691
    WRKPAY                    1.279    0.520    2.459    0.014    0.064    0.213
    WRKHSW                    5.698    2.076    2.745    0.006    0.287    0.712 
  GS =~                                                         
    GS1                       1.000                               0.268    0.406
    GS2                       1.611    0.287    5.620    0.000    0.432    0.391
    GS3                       1.764    0.317    5.557    0.000    0.473    0.380
    GS4.                      1.277    0.217    5.898    0.000    0.342    0.547

Covariances:
                           Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  SE ~~                                                       
    SA.                       0.210    0.024    8.570    0.000    0.604    0.604
    FR                       -0.007    0.003   -2.398    0.016   -0.233   -0.233
    GS                        0.032    0.010    3.136    0.002    0.193    0.193
  SA ~~                                                            
    FR                        0.008    0.003    2.448    0.014    0.289    0.289
    GS                        0.034    0.010    3.357    0.001    0.232    0.232
  FR ~~                                                         
    GS                       -0.002    0.001   -1.932    0.053   -0.170   -0.170

Intercepts:
                     Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .SE1               3.286    0.030   111.230    0.000    3.286    3.849
   .SE2               3.096    0.029   107.305    0.000    3.096    3.713
   .SE3               2.903    0.027   106.183    0.000    2.903    3.675
   .SE4               3.399    0.030   112.872    0.000    3.399    3.906
   .SE5               3.416    0.025   134.326    0.000    3.416    4.649
   .SA1               3.327    0.038   86.654     0.000    3.327    2.999
   .SA2               2.781    0.046   60.177     0.000    2.781    2.083
   .SA3               2.510    0.042   59.943     0.000    2.510    2.074
   .SA4               3.181    0.026   123.878    0.000    3.181    4.287
   .ABSWRK            0.254    0.015   16.856     0.000    0.254    0.583
   .WRKFRM            0.568    0.017   33.112     0.000    0.568    1.146
   .WRKPAY            0.102    0.010    9.728     0.000    0.102    0.337
   .WRKHSW            0.796    0.014   57.152     0.000    0.796    1.978
   .GS1               2.868    0.023  125.617     0.000    2.868    4.347
   .GS2               3.489    0.038   91.181     0.000    3.489    3.155
   .GS3               3.434    0.043   79.853     0.000    3.434    2.763
   .GS4               2.945    0.022  135.886     0.000    2.945    4.703
    SE                0.000                                0.000    0.000
    SA                0.000                                0.000    0.000
    FR                0.000                                0.000    0.000
    GS                0.000                                0.000    0.000

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .SE1               0.337    0.025   13.507    0.000    0.337    0.462
   .SE2               0.534    0.029   18.671    0.000    0.534    0.768
   .SE3               0.348    0.022   15.681    0.000    0.348    0.558
   .SE4               0.547    0.030   18.178    0.000    0.547    0.722
   .SE5               0.377    0.021   17.899    0.000    0.377    0.699
   .SA1               0.923    0.052   17.664    0.000    0.923    0.750
   .SA2               1.206    0.073   16.415    0.000    1.206    0.676
   .SA3               0.803    0.060   13.467    0.000    0.803    0.549
   .SA4               0.448    0.024   18.557    0.000    0.448    0.814
   .ABSWRK            0.187    0.009   20.308    0.000    0.187    0.987
   .WRKFRM            0.128    0.013    9.629    0.000    0.128    0.522
   .WRKPAY            0.087    0.004   19.993    0.000    0.087    0.955
   .WRKHSW            0.080    0.009    8.773    0.000    0.080    0.492
   .GS1               0.363    0.022   16.354    0.000    0.363    0.835
   .GS2               1.036    0.062   16.738    0.000    1.036    0.847
   .GS3               1.320    0.078   16.972    0.000    1.320    0.855
   .GS4               0.275    0.023   11.749    0.000    0.275    0.701
    SE                0.392    0.037   10.664    0.000    1.000    1.000
    SA                0.308    0.048    6.450    0.000    1.000    1.000
    FR                0.003    0.002    1.392    0.164    1.000    1.000
    GS                0.072    0.018    4.049    0.000    1.000    1.000

R-Square:
                   Estimate
    SE1               0.538
    SE2               0.232
    SE3               0.442
    SE4               0.278
    SE5               0.301
    SA1               0.250
    SA2               0.324
    SA3               0.451
    SA4               0.186
    ABSWRK            0.013
    WRKFRM            0.478
    WRKPAY            0.045
    WRKHSW            0.508
    GS1               0.165
    GS2               0.153
    GS3               0.145
    GS4               0.299
```

The loadings for ABSWRK and WRKPAY drop considerably. Is there something, after looking at both outputs, signalling to this? Should I try to transform these 4 binary variables? I have tried dropping just one of the two, and it still does not work. Conceptually, they should be linked to each other so I am not sure what other issue it could be.

Sorry if I made any mistakes or missed something basic or major, I am quite new to this! Thanks in advance!